# How to make a UINavigationBar "thin"?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

In certain places such as Mail.app, the top navigation bar is thinner in landscape mode than in portrait mode. Does anyone know how I could get something like this in my own app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior. What makes you think you're not getting this in your own app? You just need to override

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

in your view controller and return YES in all cases. The navigation bar (assuming you're using a UINavigationController) at the top will be thinner in landscape than in portrait by default.

Comment: Pretty sure he means how to make the navigation bar thing as it is in landscape, but in portrait.

Comment: I had been asking how to make in thin in landscape. I'm wondering whether or not it would work, as in Interface Builder the "simulated navigation bar" shows up as large, despite being in landscape orientation.

I tried it, and it works. Thanks!

Comment: I reported this as a bug to Apple. IB doesn't shrink the navigation bar when you rotate the interface to landscape.